# How to prevent an error if an entity in a database is not found

Tags: vb.net

I made a flashcard application where the user can edit the difficulty of each flashcard.

```
Private Sub btnHard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHard.Click
    Dim sqlstring As String = "select * from flashcards where Difficulty = 3" 'Select from flashcard table where difficulty = 3
    dataadapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstring, connection)
    dt.Clear() 'Clears datatable
    dataadapter.Fill(dt) 'Fills datatable

    Dim index = rand.Next(dt.Rows.Count) ' generates index in the range 0 .. Count - 1
    If txtBack.Visible = True Then
        txtFront.Text = dt.Rows(index)(2).ToString()
        txtBack.Visible = False
        txtBack.Text = dt.Rows(index)(3).ToString()
    Else
        MsgBox("Please first reveal the back of the flashcard")
    End If

End Sub
```

This button selects all the flashcards where difficulty is equal to 3 but if there are no records than the system produces an error. So how would I get it so the system produces a message if there are no records with that difficulty?

Comment: Just check if `dt.Rows.Count` is 0

Comment: Please don't keep hitting the database every time the user changes difficulty. Bring down all the flash cards (unless the number of cards is huge) and Select from the DataTable.

Comment: Connections need to be declared in `Using` blocks in the method where they are used. They need to be disposed with the `End Using`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub btnHard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHard.Click
    Dim sqlstring As String = "select * from flashcards where Difficulty = 3" 'Select from flashcard table where difficulty = 3
    dataadapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstring, connection)
    dt.Clear() 'Clears datatable
    dataadapter.Fill(dt) 'Fills datatable

    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then 'If record is not found in the database
        MsgBox("There are no more flashcards inside this deck")
        Exit Sub 'Code continus running if record is found
    End If

    Dim index = rand.Next(dt.Rows.Count) ' generates index in the range 0 .. Count - 1
    If txtBack.Visible = True Then 'If the back of the flashcard is shown
        txtFront.Text = dt.Rows(index)(2).ToString() 'Displays a random record in the third column (front of flashcard)
        txtBack.Visible = False 'Does not display the back of the flashcard
        txtBack.Text = dt.Rows(index)(3).ToString() 'Displays a random record in the fourth column ()
    Else 'If the user has not pressed the reveal button before
        MsgBox("Please first reveal the back of the flashcard")
    End If
End Sub
```